# No src property for Adobe PDF Reader control (axAcroPDF, COM control)

Tags: vb.net, pdf, acrobat

I'm testing using the Adobe PDF Reader control from `AcroPDF.dll` library. To add it, I go in the Toolbox, choose "Choose items...", go in the COM tab, etc.

I add it in my form successfully, but when I try to access the `src` property like in [this tutorial](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/visual-basic-pdf-reader.htm), the property doesn't exist.

What's the problem ? Should I try to find another version of the library and manually add it to toolbox ? Or something like this ?

Comment: I have both the `src` property and the `LoadFile()` method. Did you try updating to the latest version of Adobe Reader? You could try browsing for the DLL (thus manually adding it, as you said). It should be located in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Maybe you could give me your DLL?

Comment: Indeed I could. I'll upload it when I get access to a computer.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.mydoomsite.com/sourcecodes/AcroPDF.zip

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem, [here's](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/f959j223d6kltt3/AcroPDF.zip) the download link to a working `AcroPDF.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the latest version of Adobe Reader, install it and re-add it to the form. Then check if other properties are available, you may find the properties documentation for the interface [here](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.167.html). Also try to use [LoadFile()](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?href=IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.175.html#1522383&accessible=true) method to load PDF file.